# How to match array and object iterators?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, data-structures

I have a pizzaPriceCalculator function that takes in 3 arguments: sauce (String), toppings (initially String) and  loyalCustomer (boolean).

I have 2 dictionaries: sauceMenu and toppingsMenu like this:

```
  sauceMenu = {
    "regular": 4.35,
    "alfredo": 4.6,
    "marinara": 5.85,
    "mix": 5.47
  }
  toppingsMenu = {
    "cheese": 0.5,
    "pepperoni": 0.75,
    "salami": 0.65,
    "olives": 1.0,
    "mushroom": 0.35
  }
```

Function is called this way:

```
pizzaPriceCalculator("marinara", "pepperoni", True)
```

I just iterate through both dictionaries, return costs if there is a match and sum sauce and topping costs to print the final price.

Here is the full code:

```
def pizzaPriceCalculator (sauce, toppings, loyalCustomer):
  sauceMenu = {
    "regular": 4.35,
    "alfredo": 4.6,
    "marinara": 5.85,
    "mix": 5.47
  }

  toppingsMenu = {
    "cheese": 0.5,
    "pepperoni": 0.75,
    "salami": 0.65,
    "olives": 1.0,
    "mushroom": 0.35
  }

  for i in sauceMenu:
    if sauce is i:
      print(sauceMenu[i])
      baseTeaAmount = sauceMenu[i]

      for j in toppingsMenu:
        if toppings is j:
          print(toppingsMenu[j])
          toppingsAmount = toppingsMenu[j]

          priceBeforeDiscount = baseTeaAmount + toppingsAmount
          print(priceBeforeDiscount)

          if loyalCustomer:
            priceAfterDiscount = priceBeforeDiscount - 1
            print(priceAfterDiscount)
            # return priceAfterDiscount;


pizzaPriceCalculator("marinara", "pepperoni", True)
```

The problem is that I was told to refactor the code and make 2nd argument (toppings) a list of strings so you can pick many toppings.

```
 pizzaPriceCalculator("marinara", ["pepperoni", "cheese", "olives"], True)
```

How do I match an array iterator and object iterator so it sums sauce and all toppings?

I've tried to iterate through the toppings list (from input) and check if it matches our toppingsMenu dictionary iterator but it doesn't work:

```
for j in toppingsMenu:
    for k in toppings:    
        if toppings[k] is j:
            print(toppingsMenu[j])
            toppingsAmount = toppingsMenu[j]
```

Also how do I add all picked topping prices to each other and finally to sauce price to get the final cost?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It seems kind of redundant to set the sauceMenu and toppingsMenu prices every time you call the function - considering that the prices are not changing from call to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below code. Assuming, for sauce the input is just one item in string & toppings will be a list of many items...

```
def pizzaPriceCalculator (sauce, toppings, loyalCustomer): 
    sauceMenu = {"regular": 4.35, "alfredo": 4.6, "marinara": 5.85, "mix": 5.47} 
    toppingsMenu = {"cheese": 0.5, "pepperoni": 0.75, "salami": 0.65, "olives": 1.0, "mushroom": 0.35}
        
    baseTeaAmount = sauceMenu[sauce]
    
    toppingsAmount = 0
    for item in toppings:
        toppingsAmount = toppingsAmount + toppingsMenu[item]
        
    priceBeforeDiscount = baseTeaAmount + toppingsAmount

    if loyalCustomer:
        priceAfterDiscount = priceBeforeDiscount - 1
        print(priceAfterDiscount)
    else:
        print(priceBeforeDiscount)


           
pizzaPriceCalculator("marinara", ["pepperoni", "cheese", "olives"], True)

# 7.1 (output)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sachin. So there is no need to iterate through each dictionary using syntax 'for i in sauce menu'? I didn't know you can just do sauceMenu[sauce] and toppingsMenu[item] to loop through dictionaries. Just to clarify, we are still looping through each dictionary, right?

Comment: Glad to help @BBeknaz0904... & Yes, we can get the value by just calling the dictionary as dict[key]... & we are not looping through the dictionary... for sauce as its just one item, so simply called the dict... & for toppings, we are looping through the item of it's list & fetching the values from dictionary toppingsMenu... Thanks... Drop a like & accept the best answer that works for your problem statement... To grow & motivate community... Happy Coding :)

Comment: Could you please assist with a small refactor. What if I cannot use dictionaries to store data but need to use Lists instead?  Imagine sauceMenu and toppingsMenu are 2 Lists. Could you please share the code for that?